# Using a dropdownlist from one <asp> section to update a grid view in another <asp> section

Tags: asp.net

I have the above problem, if I include the dropdownlist, data source and grid view in one  section it works fine. But I need to have the grid view in another central section  whilst keeping the dropdownlist box to the left.
I hoped I could use left1.sqldatasource or left1/sqldatasource but these dont work.

Any ideas how I reference this dropdownlist in my central grid view?

**CODE**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="left1" runat="server">

<div id="head2">
    Start here:
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Please select Genre</asp:ListItem>        
        <asp:ListItem>Chart</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>House</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Techno</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Dubstep</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Drum and Bass</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>        
    </div>    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="center1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BETable1]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Show" HeaderText="Show" SortExpression="Show" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" HeaderText="Genre" SortExpression="Genre" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Venue" HeaderText="Venue" SortExpression="Venue" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it sounds like you want to raise an event when the dropdown list is changed and handle it in the parent: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-event-handlers-in-aspnet-web-pages-and-controls

Comment: Im trying to add the code but its all over the place and very unformatted.

Comment: Heres the dropdownlist contained in the first asp section.

Comment: [code]<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="left1" runat="server">

    <div id="head2">
        Start here:
&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>Chart</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>House</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Alternative</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dubstep</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Drum and Bas</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Techno</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Water Sports</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>[/code]

Comment: I cant add formatted code yet as I have to wait 8 hours it seems.

Comment: Formatted code added.

Comment: Could you be more specific please. What is it doing? What should it be doing? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="left1" runat="server">

<div id="head2">
    Start here:
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Please select Genre</asp:ListItem>        
        <asp:ListItem>Chart</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>House</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Techno</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Dubstep</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Drum and Bass</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>        
    </div>    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="center1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BETable1]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Show" HeaderText="Show" SortExpression="Show" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" HeaderText="Genre" SortExpression="Genre" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Venue" HeaderText="Venue" SortExpression="Venue" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the  sectioning and instead kept the divisions as .
I would liked to have completed it the  section method but needs must and assignment is due this week.